# Adding items to a Listbox using Entries from another class

Tags: linux, forms, python-2.7, oop, tkinter

I have created two classes, one is in `People.py` (which will be the parent class) which contains a list box that can be populated by just opening a file and adding content to the list box line by line.

Another class is in `Names.py` (which I want it to be child class), which contains entries of first name, last name, and a combo box for titles that should (will implement once question/problem is answered) go into the list in the main window where the class is `People`. I am trying to use an OOP model. Right now, it's not fully OOP, but I will refactor the code later.

I have tried posting this code before but people are having trouble running it due to indentation problems, so I'm providing the links to the classes. In Dropbox [Name Class](http://dropbox.com/s/nn3yuwoiil0iep6/Names.py?dl=0) and [People Class:](http://dropbox.com/s/t70l6ggjw8t2hvp/People.py?dl=0)

Note: I'm running this in a Linux environment, so you may have to modify the file choosing line in the `People` class if using Windows (or another OS).

```
f = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you still have a problem of `inconsistent use of tabs and spaces`, which I solved, but maybe other people cannot solve it.

First of all, you should name your files/modules with lower cases (by convention, and you should follow it!). Then, in `Names.py` you are doing `from Tkinter import *` and then `from Tkinter import Tk`, which does not make any sense: with the first you are already importing `Tk`.

Your problem is the following:

> People.people_list.insert(Tk.END, FirstName.get()) AttributeError:
>
> 'module' object has no attribute 'people_list'

In fact, you are trying to access an inexistent attribute of the **module** `People` called `people_list`, which is a local variable to some functions, from what I have been seeing.

If you want to fill a `Listbox` which is a property of some Toplevel `A`, with the input from another Toplevel `B`, you should pass a reference of the Toplevel `A` to `B`, maybe during its construction.

Here you have an example:

```
from tkinter import *  # python 3


class Other(Toplevel):

    """Note that the constructor of this class
    receives a parent called 'master' and a reference to another Toplevel
    called 'other'"""

    def __init__(self, master, other):
        
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.other = other # other Toplevel

        self.lab = Label(self, text="Insert your name: ")
        self.lab.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # When you click the button you call 'self.add'
        self.adder = Button(self, text='Add to Listbox', command=self.add)
        self.adder.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def add(self):
        """Using a reference to the other window 'other', 
        I can access its attribute 'listbox' and insert a new item!"""
        self.other.listbox.insert("end", self.entry.get())
       

class Main(Toplevel):

    """Window with a Listbox"""
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.people = Label(self, text='People')
        self.people.grid(row=0)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.grid(row=1)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # hides Tk window

    main = Main(root)
    Other(root, main)  # passing a reference of 'main'

    root.mainloop()
```

I noticed also that you are using 2 instance of `Tk` for each of your windows, which is bad. You should use just one instance of `Tk` for every application. If you want to use multiple windows, just use `Toplevels`, as I mentioned.

In general, your structure is not so good. You should start by creating simple good applications, and then pass to big ones once you grasp the basic concepts.